# how to make a bat file autostart in win system

Tags: batch-file, autostart

I have a bat file (in fact it is a tomcat startup bat), this is the very simple content:

```
c:/tomcat/catalina.bat run
```

Now I want it to autostart at system startup, any ideas?

Comment: Put a shortcut to the file in the Startup folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify more what @Oskar said. The autostart is the **startup folder in your Program Files folder.**
Any executable files placed in that folder are launched on windows startup.

Comment: I am sorry but I really can not find where the autostart folder under c:/program files. I have set to see all the hide file and folders,what is the problem?

Comment: the folder name is "Startup". If it doesn't exist, create it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to start it when you are logged in then put it in start list, just create shortcut to bat file in startup folder start->programs->startup